# MATLAB Eye Recognition

Tags: matlab, face-recognition

Is it possible to detect eye in the video mode in MATLAB? 
 I am trying to detect the eye and make some predictions based on the movement of the eye. 
 But am not sure on how to do that. Can someone help me in how to start about that? 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at this set of functions on The MathWorks File Exchange: [Fast Eyetracking](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25056) by [Peter Aldrian](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/65834).

Quoting from the description of the post (to give a little more detail here):

> This project handles with the question 
>   how to extract fixed feature points
>   from a given face in a real time
>   environment. It is based on the idea,
>   that a face is given by Viola Jones
>   Algorithm for face detection and
>   processed to track pupil movement in
>   relation to the face without using
>   infrared light.

Comment: I was going to suggest using Haar-like features for face detection (followed by eye tracking). Looks like this solution already implements that.

Answer (score 0):

My MATLAB is incredibly rusty, but [this site](http://www.urwelcome.us/Jstill/Matlab/Eye_Tracking.htm) appears to have some scripts to help track eye movement.

Answer (score 0):

eye detection will be possible with MATLAB and you can come up with that. But there is a difference between recognition and detection that you need to consider carefully. Detection is checking if an object is available in the image whereas recognition is determining what the different objects in the image are.
I hope it'll increase someone's knowledge.